# How to validate an IEnumerable is not null or empty using DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying validate an `IEnumerable<long> selectedItems` if does not null or empty but I can't do this, it needs to has one or more options selected because its a multiple option. How could I do this ?

trying.

**Model**

```
public class EmpresaModel{

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> formasPagto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose one or more options")]
    public IEnumerable<long> selectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.selectedItems)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Formas de pagamento disponíveis <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
           @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedItems, Model.formasPagto, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Selecione as formas de pagamento disponíveis", @multiple = true})
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.formasPagto)
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use validation data annotations on IEnumerable<T> typed properties.

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran So, how could I do validate this property ? I need to check if it doesn't empty because the user needs to select one or more options. Any idea ?

Comment: Just add the `[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select at least one ... ")]` attribute to property `selectedItems` (and remove `@multiple = true` - that is already been added by the `ListBoxFor()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke works like charm, thanks a lot !